# How to attribute QMediaPlayer to QWidget from UI? To get the effect of filled QWidget field

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

## Hello,

I am creating UI for my smart home project using Qt. I met proble with ascribe widgets. What I want to do is ascribe QMediaPlayer to QWidget in order to inherit QWidget parameters (for instance - window on UI).

**So far I created mainwindow.ui:**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaFeJ.png)

In mainwindow.ui you can see groupBox(named camera) which includes gridLayout including QWidget.

**Using this part of code:**

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    _vw = new QVideoWidget;
    _player = new QMediaPlayer(ui->cameraWidget);
    ui->gridLayout_2->addWidget(_vw);
    _player->setVideoOutput(_vw);

    const QUrl url = QUrl("rtsp://192.168.200.102:5554/playlist.m3u");
    const QNetworkRequest requestRtsp(url);
    _player->setMedia(requestRtsp);
    _player->play();
}
```

**I get following - not satisfied result:**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElLFE.png)

I want to fill 100% of QWidget space(named cameraWidget) by QMediaPlayer.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't completely understand your problem.  Is it to do with the size of the widgets?  Have you tried resizing them?  Try looking at their size hints.

Comment: I found solution. Later I will upload the code.